# Why tabindex='-1' prevents keyboard

Tags: html, modal-dialog, tabindex

After many hours trying to locate why a keyboard input would not work within a bootstrap modal, i have finally managed to identify the issue.. and it was something i would have never of thought of, but found it by pure process of elimination.

By having `tabindex='-1'` present on the `<div>` for the modal from bootstrap, it completely stops the input from the keyboard. I would have thought the data-attribute `data-keyboard="false"` would have been the culprit however it was not.

**My Question**
`Why does tabindex='-1' prevent keyboard input. And what would be its purpose other than that?`

Comment: This attribute is used to set up tab navigation (hitting Tab key to jump from a field to another) according to documentation, setting any negative value will remove it from tab navigation, but it can still be focused by script command or mouse click and interated with. I'm not sure why you are being unable to input content on whatever you are setting that property.

Comment: Example http://jsfiddle.net/D6cV5/

Comment: An attribute like `data-keyboard` as such as absolutely no effect on functionality, and it has no predefined meaning, any more than `data-dhedhgjghjfhg` has. It simply sets an attribute that may be safely used in client-side scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabindex` sets the order that editable-elements on the page will be iterated using the `tab` key. `-1` seems like a reasonable value, from that sense, to make an element unapproachable.

For more information: http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex